# In wso2 esb how to convert text/html to application/json

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

In wso2 esb response I am getting is

```
{"success":true,"data":"1234"}
```

with header text/html so i tried to convert with

```
<property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
<property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
```

But i am data in binary form like this.

```
    {
    "binary": "eyJzdWNjZXNzIjp0cnVlLCJkYXRhIjoie1wicmF0ZV9oclwiOjIwLFwicmV2ZW51ZVwiOjEwMCxcIm5leHRfZGF5X3ByZWRpY3RlZFwiOjEwMH0ifQ=="
}
```

So how to get json data

Comment: Did you enable the relevant message builder for application/json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As wso2 ESB message builder for text/html converts text to binary format while processing.

I solved this problem like this.

Step 1-->To get the payload.
Script mediator:

```
<script language="js"><![CDATA[var temp = mc.getPayloadXML();

 mc.setProperty("RESPONSE", temp);]]></script>
```

Step 2-->To convert binary to string.
Property mediator:

```
<property expression="base64Decode(get-property('RESPONSE'))"
        name="DecodeBody" scope="default" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
```

Step 3-->String to JSON
Script mediator:

```
<script language="groovy"><![CDATA[
import groovy.json.*;
String s=mc.getProperty("DecodeBody");

def processed = new JsonSlurper().parseText(s.toString());
mc.setPayloadJSON(JsonOutput.toJson(processed));
]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case, i was calling an endpoint that return text/html, and WSO2 was throwing an exception when receiving the response, so i solve it by adding the following entries to conf/axis2/axis2.xml, each in the correct section:

```
    <messageFormatter contentType="text/html" 
    class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamFormatter"/>

   <messageBuilder contentType="text/html" 
   class="org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonStreamBuilder"/>
```